# Using regex to look into a list

Tags: python

This is my first question ever, so please bear with me here. I have below set of python code, but I expect a "match" to be printed, instead I get a "No match". What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
import re
items = ("t1", "s1")

for i in items:
    x = re.search("t.", i)

if x:
  print("match")
else:
  print("No match")
```

**output**

```
No match
```

Answer (score 3):

Your if block is outside of for loop, thus only last value of it is checked.
You should indent it like:

```py
for i in items:
    x = re.search("t.", i)

    if x:
        print("match")
    else:
        print("No match")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code goes like this:

1. You take "t1"
2. Check if it matches with "t."
3. It matches, save `true` in `x`
4. You take "s1"
5. Check if it matches with "t."
6. It does not match, save `false` in `x`
7. check `x` and do something

Notice how you overwrite `x` to false at point 6?
This is why your output is "no match"